# What do these diode part numbers mean?

Tags: identification, specifications

While selecting a diode, I came across [these](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-semiconductor-diodes-division/1N5408-E3-54/1N5408-E3-54GICT-ND/190152) [two](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-semiconductor-diodes-division/1N5408-E3-73/1N5408-E3-73GICT-ND/3711763), which appear to be the same, save the ending part numbers after a "/" (i.e. one is 54, the other 73). I've surmised from [JEDEC 609B](https://www.jedec.org/system/files/docs/J-STD-609B.pdf) section 5.3 that the "E3" refers to the leads being pure tin; section 5.1 mentions a "slash-sheet" number, but this refers to PCB base materials, and according to section 7.9, should come before the "E3" designation.

I haven't found an answer in the [datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88516/1n5400.pdf). What do the numbers after the slash ("/") mean?

Comment: Packaging for auto feeders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Ordering Information" table generally lists all the available part number variations and their meaning.

for the 1N5404, "/54" is tape and reel, while "/73" is ammo pack - on tape, but with the tape folded into a box.

Comment: correct: Link to the vishay packaging info https://www.vishay.com/docs/88869/packaging.pdf  Tip: search for 1N5408 at vishay and you will get to this information pretty fast in the document tab